# Is it possible to use Kotlin in Grails?

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, kotlin

Some basic facts that lead me to this question:

- Groovy has complete Java interoperability
- Kotlin has complete Java interoperability
- Kotlin also compiles down to Java

Is it therefore possible to write Kotlin code in a Grails application?

I've worked quite a bit with Grails 2.x, and recently at a new job I have been working with Kotlin, Spring, and Struts. I **really** like the null-safety and type inference features of Kotlin, and the functional programming features of Kotlin feel much more natural and easy to use than in Groovy (this last part is pure opinion).

Is it possible to use Grails to handle things like:

- ORM
- Mapping requests to controllers/actions
- JSP/GSP view parsing/rendering

but use Kotlin to write the actual logic of the domain classes, controller actions, services, object factories, etc.

Probably not likely, because I'm guessing that some of the core functionality of Grails is made possible by dynamic typing, but maybe it could be possible through either a Gradle plugin or a direct Grails plugin.

I like the extreme simplicity provided by the convention-over-configuration paradigm of Grails, but I much prefer the static typing and type inference of Kotlin.

If I could write business logic in Kotlin in a Grails environment, that, to me, would be the ultimate web application framework!

Comment: _I really like the null-safety and type inference features of Kotlin_. The irony is that [these features](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#type-inference) were [directly taken from Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator). Those "cool features" mentioned about Kotlin has been the salient features of Groovy right from the inception of the language. I would love to see more example of _the functional programming features of Kotlin feel much more natural and easy to use than in Groovy_, if you can share some examples.

Comment: I meant to imply that I prefer the statically typed nature of Kotlin, particularly things like the builtin `data class`, and `var` vs. `val` vs. `fun`, and the nullable vs. non-nullable types. @AbhijitSarkar I use Kotlin with Spring at work and our entire web app is built in some Java and mostly Kotlin. P.S. I sort of enjoyed clojure for a while lol

Comment: Spring has 1st class support for Kotlin. Grails doesn't-you're trying to shoehorn it into submission.

Comment: @MatJones - "I sort of enjoyed clojure for a while" - You can also use Clojure in a Grails app.  In early versions of Grails I wrote the plugin `grails-clojure` plugin to demonstrate that it can be somewhat trivial to add support for new languages. You can't write Grails components like Controllers and TagLibs with Clojure, but you can write all of your application logic in Clojure, or Scala, or Kotlin, or some other JVM language that you invent tomorrow. The system is quite flexible, largely due to flexibility provided by the JVM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is it therefore possible to write Kotlin code in a Grails application?

Definitely.  You can use any JVM language from a Grails app.  I built a proof of concept with Kotlin in Grails and everything worked just as one would hope: https://github.com/jeffbrown/langdemo

Comment: Can I get a link to the proof of concept project?

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer if you can provide some examples/tutorials/suggested readings

Comment: The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/langdemo demonstrates injecting a Spring bean written in Kotlin which implements a Java interface into a Groovy controller.  They all play quite nicely together.  See https://github.com/jeffbrown/langdemo/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy, https://github.com/jeffbrown/langdemo/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/KotlinMathHelper.kt, https://github.com/jeffbrown/langdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/MathHelper.java.

Comment: "I'll mark this as the correct answer if you can provide some examples/tutorials/suggested readings" - I don't really mind one way or the other if you mark the answer as correct or not.  I was addressing the question as asked "Is it therefore possible to write Kotlin code in a Grails application?".  It is.  I hope that helps.

Comment: This is a Grails 3.x example, is it also possible in a Grails 2.5?

Comment: @Michael - Yes.  It would take a small bit more work to setup the build, but yes.

Comment: The build is what I was most curious about since 2.x doesn't use Gradle.

Comment: Gradle isn't necessary to use Kotlin in any project, Grails projects included.